# Remove unnecessary quotes from sender display name with special characters

Tags: postfix, email-server, smtp-headers, squirrelmail

I have set up Postfix with Dovecot and SquirrelMail on an Ubunutu 18.04 machine. Everything is working great, except for the display name with special characters.

In SquirrelMail, I have configured the Full Name to be **Õäöü**:

[image: Squirrelmail full name options]

But when I receive the email in, e.g. Gmail, I can see the display name as **"Õäöü"** (with quotes):

[image]

It only happens when I have special characters in the name. If the name has only ASCII characters, there are no extra quotes added. Inspecting the message headers in both cases, you can see why this happens:

- In case of **Oaou**: `From: Oaou <info@example.com>`
- In case of **Õäöü**: `From: "\"Õäöü\"" <info@example.com>`

The special characters get encapsulated in double-quotes **twice**. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for the record, I can't reproduce this using the most up to date version of SquirrelMail.

You need to post the version of SquirrelMail you're using, and show things like what you've set for configuration settings such as `$default_charset`, `$squirrelmail_default_language` and `$lossy_encoding` and what language the user interface is set to when composing.

Then show the actual email header from the message source on the recipient side.

I suspect this can be solved by making sure you are running the latest code from [the SquirrelMail download page](https://squirrelmail.org/download.php) and setting `$default_charset` to utf-8 unless you're using some language which isn't translated in UTF encoding (and if so, you need to say so and try the same test while the interface is set to English).

For detailed issues like this you're much more likely to get assistance on the [SquirrelMail mailing lists or tracker](https://squirrelmail.org/docs/admin/admin-12.html).